# Synonymous to "Have had enough of "

Tags: phrases, synonyms

When you're tired of a situation, you can use the pattern

> *...have had enough of*

For instance:

> Peter has had enough of the quarrel between his mother and wife.

1. What patterns can I also add after the sentence to emphasize the sentence?
2. Are there any common synonymous to the phrase?

Thank you.

Comment: [Fed up](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/fed%20up).  "Peter was fed up with ...."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure what you mean by the first question (elaboration please), but here are some common synonyms to q.2:

Peter **is tired of** the quarrel between his mother and wife.

Peter **is sick of** the quarrel between his mother and wife. (*informal*)

Peter **is bored of/getting bored of** the quarrel between his mother and wife.

Peter **can't stand** the quarrel between his mother and wife.

Peter **has lost the will to live** over the quarrel between his mother and wife. (*informal*)

Peter **abhors** the quarrel between his mother and wife.

Peter **despises** the quarrel between his mother and wife.

Peter **is disgusted with** the quarrel between his mother and wife.

Comment: To emphasize the impatience. To make the emotion stronger.

Comment: Oh yes of course!  In the last three, I've answered that anyway!

Comment: I've *had it up to here* with these synonyms!!

Answer (score 1):

A possible appendage might be

> [...] to last for a lifetime.

as in

> I've had enough ice cream to last for a lifetime.

or a strong exaggeration, for example

> I've had enough ice cream to fill myself to the moon and back, twice!

Comment: Have had enough 'of'(?) Can I ignore the word 'of' before adding a subject after it.

Comment: @Stallman Yes, as long as the 'enough' in not followed by a pronoun or determiner.
Example: I have had enough **of** _your_ ice cream.